# Cypress - Getting error while executing 'cypress open'

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, cypress

I've a Testing framework with node, cypress, mocha, mochawesome and mochawesome-merge as below with [this github repo](https://github.com/far11ven/Cypress-TestFramework/tree/develop):

[image]

and in my package.json I have two scripts as

```
`"scripts": {
    "cy": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress open",
    "cy_test": "node cypress.js"
  },`
```

If I run `npm run cy_test` it works fine in headless state, but if I run `npm run cy` i get following error:

[image]

But If I remove cypress.js from my project then it works as expected.

**cypress.js**

```
const cypress = require('cypress')
const marge = require('mochawesome-report-generator')
const { merge } = require('mochawesome-merge')

const currRunTimestamp = getTimeStamp();

const mergedReport = {
    reportDir: 'mochawesome-report',
}

const finalReport = {
    reportDir: 'reports',
}

cypress.run({
    reporter: 'mochawesome',
    reporterOptions: {
        reportDir: 'mochawesome-report',
        overwrite: false,
        html: true,
        json: true
      }
    }).then(
    () => {
        generateReport()
    },
    error => {
        generateReport()
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    }
)

function generateReport(options) {
    return merge(mergedReport).then(report => marge.create(report, finalReport))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a problem with `npm` on Windows that is messing with file names, because `npm` is trying to run the script as binary instead of getting it from `./node_modules/.bin`.

So, I'll suggest, as first try, if you can, change the name of the `cypress.js` to something other than `cypress`. I think this can solve your problem.

If not, as a workaround remove `.JS` from `PATHEXT` environment variable and restart the processes that are running the script, including your IDE, if applicable.

Hope it works.

Comment: Hi Diogo, I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: changing `cypress.js` to `cy_test.js` did the trick. Thanks!!